# Make property optional if all its children are optional

Tags: typescript

How do I make properties of an object optional:

- if it is already optional
- if it isn't optional, if all its inner properties are optional

The would be for it to work recursively for a whole record, so the properties of the properties of the root of my objects are also rendered optional if the rules are matched.

```
type Given = {
  p1: string;
  p2?: number;
  p3: {
    p31: string;
  };
  p4: {
    p41?: string;
  };
  p5: {
    p51: string;
    p52: number;
  };
  p6: {
    p61: string;
    p62?: number;
  };
  p7: {
    p71?: string;
    p72?: number;
  };
  p8?: {
    p81: string;
  };
  p9: {
    p91: {
      p911: {
        p9111?: string;
      };
    };
  };
}
```

I should get following:

```
type Expected = {
  p1: string;
  p2?: number;
  p3: {
    p31: string;
  };
  p4?: {
    p41?: string;
  };
  p5: {
    p51: string;
    p52: number;
  };
  p6: {
    p61: string;
    p62?: number;
  };
  p7?: {
    p71?: string;
    p72?: number;
  };
  p8?: {
    p81: string;
  };
  p9?: {
    p91?: {
      p911?: {
        p9111?: string;
      };
    };
  };
}
```

I already tried some solutions with `extends` but I can't find a way to match the fact that all properties match a condition.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By "this should work deeply", do you mean to arbitrary depth, or is up to the second level like in you example enough?

Comment: When you say "if and only if" it implies that a property *shouldn't* be optional if it doesn't have all-optional children, but that would mean you'd want `{a?: {b: string}}` converted to `{a: {b: string}}`.  I kind of doubt that's what you want, so could you make it more clear?  Also, if you want it to work "deeply" could you provide a [mre] of such a type where the difference matters?  Like, what should `{x: {y: {z: {}}}}` become?  (note: `{}` has "all optional properties" logically).  What should `{x: {y: {z: {a?: number}}}}` become? etc.

Comment: I've got something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3aO1w) but there are so many potential edge cases that I will wait until you clarify and provide some more examples before I answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've edited:

How do I make properties of an object optional:

- if it is already optional
- if it isn't optional, if all its inner properties are optional

I've also added an example of the depth.

Comment: Your solution is great @jcalz, unfortunately it doesn't work with `Date`

Types of property 'startDate' are incompatible.
  Types of property 'toDateString' are incompatible.

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/NDzbzW This one seems to fit my needs

Comment: That's a brittle solution unless you *never* transform `interface` types (see [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPxGKW)).  In actuality the problem is `Date` is an object type so the transformer transforms it as well; can you come up with a coherent criterion to distinguish object types that you want to transform from ones you don't?